# how to drag a wedge from pie chart which is developed using coreplot in iphone

Tags: iphone, ipad, core-plot, pie-chart

hi people i had drawn a piechart using coreplots in my application,now i need to split a piechart into different pieces/objects and need to drag those objects.How to achieve this functionality.Thanks in Adv[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy, you just have to do a lot of custom programming. Read the Apple developer documentation and stackoverflow for useful tips on handling touches using UIGestureRecognizer and moving/animating UIView.

Comment: do you have any idea of creating 3d piecharts. i mean do you know about any exiting framworks.??

Comment: No, please edit your question to clarify that you are looking for another charting library. Right now it looks as if you're asking for help on dragging using touches.

Comment: i just need it for both the things so?either 2d r 3d.

Comment: AFAIK there are no existing frameworks that will do this for you out of the box.